# Container for tasks created by asyncio.create_task

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Am trying to create tasks to be collected in a set for processing later with `await`s the following code.

```
import asyncio
import random

async def coro(s):
    await asyncio.sleep(s)
    print(f"Slept for {s} seconds")
    return s

tasks = set() # collector for tasks created

async def main():
    for _ in range(3):
        s = random.uniform(0.05, 1)
        tasks.update(asyncio.create_task(coro(s))) # fails!

    print(tasks)
    
    ...

    return tasks

result = asyncio.run(main())

print(result)
```

...but it gives `RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future`

Where am I going wrong? How can I collect a set of tasks created?

Comment: Use `tasks.add()` to add new item instead of `update()`

Answer (score 1):

As @alex pointed out, corrected the silly mistake with `tasks.add`

```
...
async def main():
    for _ in range(3):
        s = random.uniform(0.05, 1)
        tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(coro(s))) # passes!
...
```